tinyMCE: Admonition button
Can someone help me how I can add admonition to my existing tinyMCE installation? I use tinyMCE as an editor for my knowledgebase, without wordpress.
I would like an admonition button with which I can simply insert an admonition in the text. unfortunately I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.
